# Copying Documents between subsites and staying connected

Tags: 2013, document-library, document

Working in SP13. I know there is a way, but I can't remember how to do it.

Scenario:  I have a document that's in Document Library A.  I want to copy a document from Document Library A to Document Library B that's in another subsite.

Problem: I have been able to copy document from Document Library A to Document Library B (in new subsite) but when I update document in Document Library A the changes do not show in Document Library B (in new subsite).

Can anyone tell what I doing wrong?

I used Copy Items button. Did not see options for connections.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Pleas refer to this link](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/move-or-copy-files-in-sharepoint-00e2f483-4df3-46be-a861-1f5f0c1a87bc#ID0EAABAAA=2016,_2013), hope this helps!